# Ignore Attribute does't work CassandraCSharpDriver

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using some properties in Entity model for maintaining relationships, I am using `[Ignore]` for ignoring that property from table.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        [Ignore]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CommonName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

var User = new Table<User>(dataSession);
                User.CreateIfNotExists();
```

When i try to create using above code i get error.

[image]

**Question:** Am i using wrong script for creating table or wrong way to ignore?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you are using the correct namespace for the `Ignore` attribute. `Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.Ignore` is the correct one and the other one is deprecated.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();
            var session = cluster.Connect();

            var User = new Table<User>(session, MappingConfiguration.Global, "users", "testks");
            User.CreateIfNotExists();
            var u = new User
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Password = "123",
                FirstName = "123",
                LastName = "123",
                CommonName = "123",
                ProfilePhoto = "321",
                IsDeleted = false,
                UserRoles = new List<UserRole>
                {
                    new UserRole
                    {
                        Text = "text"
                    }
                }
            };
            User.Insert(u).Execute();
            var result = User.First(l => l.Id == u.Id).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
            Console.ReadLine();
            User.Where(l => l.Id == u.Id).Delete().Execute();
        }
    }

    public class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.Ignore]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CommonName { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.Ignore]
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class IdentityUser<T>
    {
        [Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes.PartitionKey]
        public T Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserRole
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

Running the code above against Cassandra `3.0.18` with C# driver `3.10.1` seems to work correctly. The `Password` and `UserRoles` will not exist in the table schema and they will both be `null` when executing `SELECT` statements with `Linq2Cql`.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I have problem, when i use Identity package. "Microsoft.Aspnetcore.Identity".

Comment: What problem do you have? Do you need to add an attribute to a class of that package? If that is the case, then you have two options:

1 - Create your own class to use with the C# driver and perform the mapping manually after you perform the database operation

2 - Use Mapper instead of Linq2Cql to configure the Mapping: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.10/features/components/mapper/#configuring-mappings

Answer (score 0):

Check out this type list for Cassandra to C#.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.7/features/datatypes/

Instead of ICollection maybe use IEnumerable or maybe even, depending on what you're aiming to do a IDictionary.

Comment: It doesn't matter which property of which type i am using, i just want cassandra to ignore this.
What is your answer? i have to change the property to some specific type to ignore?